# Getting specific Data from a form symfony2

Tags: php, forms, symfony

My problem is that I want to set a value to one field of an Entity and this value comes from a form.

The form is bound to another entity and this field of the form is named `fmedida`.

This is what I've tried

```
$hijo-> setFinicio(new \DateTime($form->getData()->getfmedida()));
```

But of course the syntax is not correct since I have this error message:

> "DateTime::__construct() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given"

Comment: Is the data in fmedida a date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I advise you to var_dump the value that you get from `$form->getData()->getfmedida()` and see what is happening.

When I tried getData(), it returns array on my side, so also try:

```
$data = $form->getData();
$fmedida = $data['fmedida'];

$hijo-> setFinicio(new \DateTime($fmedida));
```

Also, DateTime creates DateTime objects from strings. Obviously, the value which you are getting from  `$form->getData()->getfmedida()` is not a string, it's a object. If `$form->getData()->getfmedida()` gives you a DateTime object, I can't  see a point in using DateTime, so just

```
$hijo-> setFinicio($form->getData()->getfmedida());
```

should be enough.

Comment: It was your last option gracias!